# Reset slide counter after \pause in Latex Beamer

Tags: graphics, beamer

```
\begin{itemize}
\item text1
\pause\item text2
\pause\item text3
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}

\includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth]{pics/graphic1.jpg}

\includegraphics<2-3>[width=\textwidth]{pics/graphic2.jpg}

\end{figure}
```

I want to make images appear one after the other along with the text that describes them. I've tried these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088761/how-to-change-an-image-on-a-slide-in-latex
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683093/beamer-how-to-show-images-as-step-by-step-images

But none seems to work. I came to suspect that the `\pause` is the problem. Latex seems to start counting the slides on which to let the images appear after the pauses, as if the code after the `\pause` is still affected by it, even though the itemize environment is closed. Is there a way to reset the counter? I am aware that putting the images before the itemize environment helps, but I would like to know how to make my slides exactly the way I want them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `\pause` causes problems, the solution is simple: Don't use `\pause`! Instead you can let the `itemize` environment do the uncovering for you.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item text1
            \item text2
            \item text3
        \end{itemize}

        \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics<1>[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \includegraphics<2-3>[width=.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]